# JS Array shift vs splice vs slice vs destructuring

Tags: javascript, slice, destructuring, shift, splice

Which approach to delete the first element of an array in js provides better performance?

Assume we have this array:

```
let fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Lemon'];
```

**1. shift approach**

```
let a = fruits.shift();
```

**2. splice approach**

```
let [b] = fruits.splice(0, 1);
```

**3. slice approach**

```
let c;
[c, fruits] = [...fruits.slice(0, 1), fruits.slice(1)]
```

**4. Destructuring approach**

```
let d;
[d, ...fruits] = fruits;
```

Please mention the reasons why one one these approaches is faster than another.

I did some tests in [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me) & [perf.link](https://perf.link) but I ran the exact same tests multiple times and everytime I got 180 degrees opposite results.

I know this things are different from one environment and engine to another so I want to know which one is better in Chrome V8 engine.

Comment: Why - this will depend on the environment running the code.

Comment: @evolutionxbox do you mean runtime environments? if yes, which one is better in browser or node js?

Comment: no I mean it will depend on the runtime environment. What may be fastest in Chromium might be slower in WebKit. As for testing, make your own benchmarks. https://jsbench.me/ might be helpful

Comment: @evolutionxbox well yeah, of course it depends on javascript engine. Let's say how they are different on V8 engine. I did some tests before in jsbench and another website but their responses are different everytime on the same test case and I didn't find them trusty.

Comment: Then write your own? [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) may be of use?

Comment: @evolutionxbox well I will do that but I think those websites like jsbench are doing exactly the same thing behind the scene. But I'm actually looking for a documentation or something like that, which be more trusty. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Documentation on the performance difference?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Not like documentation documentation. Something like is happening in SEO that some things explained by google and we can trust or someone that is developing V8 engine said something that we can consider. You know something more reliable than just console.time or jsbench. Now, I do not know if there is anything like that but I'm searching

Comment: Your approaches 1 and 2 are fundamentally different from approaches 3 and 4, in that they mutate the original array instead of creating a new one. Which functionality do you actually need? Only after choosing that it makes sense to benchmark the two respective cases.

Comment: Can you show the tests you did, please? Most likely you made some [microbenchmarking mistakes](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html).

Comment: @Bergi
Hi, Thank you very much. The microbenchmarking mistakes was really helpful. 

Actually I was talking about some tests that a few days ago I did to observe performance of different kinds of for loop like for...in , for...of and regular for and etc. 

And I was getting different responses but after reading this article I think I figured out the problem. 

So in short, We should do a different operation in each loop iteration to prevent being optimized and get a reliable response, right?

Comment: @DavoodTaheri No. You should benchmark your actual code in your real-world application. Only then the engine will apply (or not) the optimisations that actually matter.

Comment: @Bergi Oh Yeah, That makes sense. Thank you very much for your time. You taught me something new. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the .shift() method is the easiest to use. But if you want to know the exact code speed, I tested every method with `performance.now()`.

Mostly, the `.shift()` method is the fastest. You may ask why? Well, it doesn't redeclare any variables as the others are redefined. You only have on variable, which is automatically returned when calling the `shift()` method. Especially the last two examples are the slowest. They are redefining two variables, one is assigned two times (c, d). One time, just with let and the other time when declaring.

Here's the code I used for testing, feel free to edit it.

```js
    function speedTest(times) {
    let shiftAvg = 0;
    let spliceAvg = 0;
    let sliceAvg = 0;
    let destructuringAvg = 0;
    let t0, t1;
    let fruits = Array(10000).fill('test');
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {

        t0 = performance.now();
    
        let a = fruits.shift();
    
        t1 = performance.now();

        shiftAvg += t1 - t0;
    
        resetFruits();
        
        t0 = performance.now();
    
        let [b] = fruits.splice(0, 1);
    
        t1 = performance.now();
        spliceAvg += t1 - t0;
    
        resetFruits();
        
        t0 = performance.now();
    
        let c;
        [c, fruits] = [...fruits.slice(0, 1), fruits.slice(1)];
    
        t1 = performance.now();
        sliceAvg += t1 - t0;
    
        resetFruits();
        
        t0 = performance.now();
    
        let d;
        [d, ...fruits] = fruits;
    
        t1 = performance.now();
        destructuringAvg += t1 - t0;
    
        resetFruits();
    }
    
    shiftAvg = shiftAvg / times;
    spliceAvg = spliceAvg / times;
    sliceAvg = sliceAvg / times;
    destructuringAvg = destructuringAvg / times;

    return [
        {"avg": destructuringAvg, "approach": 'destructuring'},
        {"avg": spliceAvg, "approach": 'splice'},
        {"avg": sliceAvg, "approach": 'slice'},
        {"avg": shiftAvg, "approach": 'shift'}
    ];
    
    function resetFruits() {
        fruits = Array(10000).fill('test');
    }
}

let result = speedTest(20000).sort((a, b) => (a.avg > b.avg) ? 1 : -1);

result.map((item, index, self) => {
    if(index === 0) {
        console.log(index + 1, item.approach, item.avg, `fastest`);
    }
    else {
        console.log(index + 1, item.approach, item.avg, `${parseInt(item.avg / self[0].avg * 100 - 100)}% slower`);
    }
    
});
```

Also, not only the code execution speed is fast, but typing array.slice() is faster then for example typing out the whole destructuring code.

I hope I was able to help you out :)

Comment: I ran the example and every output except 1/slice is `0.000ms`

Comment: Yup, as I said, try running it on your own in a js code in a html document. Stack overflow isn't showing the correct results

Comment: But that clearly shows, all of those methods are very fast.

Comment: Even running it in a new tab I get `0ms` for all results. I think the difference is likely to be so small as to be insignificant.

Comment: That's probably correct. I ran it in a js file associated with a HTML document, there I got very accurate results. shift() was usually the fastest.